# Mutually recursive IO definitions

Tags: haskell

I can write the following:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f x = 0:(map (+1) x)

g :: [Int] -> [Int]
g x = map (*2) x

a = f b
b = g a

main = print $ take 5 a
```

And things work perfectly fine [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/nIjogD).

However, lets say I want `g` to do something more complex than multiply by 2, like ask the user for a number and add that, like so:

```
g2 :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
g2 = mapM (\x -> getLine >>= (return . (+x) . read))
```

How do I then, well, tie the knot?

**Clarification:**

Basically I want the list of `Int`s from `f` to be the input of `g2` and the list of `Int`s from `g2` to be the input of `f`.

Comment: You may want to look at `mfix` from `Control.Monad.Fix`.

Comment: Can you try to be more specific about what *exactly* you're trying to do?

Comment: Exactly as the example, except replace `g` with `g2`.

Answer (score 11):

The effectful generalization of lists is `ListT`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Pipes

f :: ListT IO Int -> ListT IO Int
f x = return 0 `mplus` fmap (+ 1) x

g2 :: ListT IO Int -> ListT IO Int
g2 x = do
    n  <- x
    n' <- lift (fmap read getLine)
    return (n' + n)

a = f b
b = g2 a

main = runListT $ do
    n <- a
    lift (print n)
    mzero
```

You can also implement `take` like functionality with a little extra code:

```
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes

take' :: Monad m => Int -> ListT m a -> ListT m a
take' n l = Select (enumerate l >-> Pipes.take n)

main = runListT $ do
    n <- take' 5 a
    lift (print n)
    mzero
```

Example session:

```
>>> main
0
1<Enter>
2
2<Enter>
3<Enter>
7
4<Enter>
5<Enter>
6<Enter>
18
7<Enter>
8<Enter>
9<Enter>
10<Enter>
38
```

You can learn more about `ListT` by [reading the `pipes` tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.3/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html), specifically the [section on `ListT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.3/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html#g:6).